# Cannot extend a class located in another file, PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to set up a class with commonly used tasks, such as preparing strings for input into a database and creating a PDO object. I would like to include this file in other class files and extend those classes to use the common class' code.

However, when I place the common class in its own file and include it in the class it will be used in, I receive an error that states the second class cannot be found. For example, if the class name is `foo` and it is extending `bar` (the common class, located elsewhere), the error says that `foo` cannot be found. But if I place the code for class `bar` in the same file as `foo`, it works.

Here are the classes in question - 
**Common Class**

```
abstract class coreFunctions {
    protected $contentDB;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->contentDB = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'username', 'password');
    }

    public function cleanStr($string) {
        $cleansed = trim($string);
        $cleansed = stripslashes($cleansed);
        $cleansed = strip_tags($cleansed);
        return $cleansed;
    }
}
```

**Code from individual class**

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/class.core-functions.php';
$mode = $_POST['mode'];

if (isset($mode)) {
    $gallery = new gallery;
    switch ($mode) {
        case 'addAlbum':
            $gallery->addAlbum($_POST['hash'], $_POST['title'],
                               $_POST['description']);
    }
}

class gallery extends coreFunctions {

    private function directoryPath($string) {
        $path = trim($string);
        $path = strtolower($path);
        $path = preg_replace('/[^ \pL \pN]/', '', $path);
        $path = preg_replace('[\s+]', '', $path);
        $path = substr($path, 0, 18);

        return $path;
    }
    public function addAlbum($hash, $title, $description) {
        $title = $this->cleanStr($title);
        $description = $this->cleanStr($description);
        $path = $this->directoryPath($title);

        if ($title && $description && $hash) {
            $addAlbum = $this->contentDB->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery_albums
                                        (albumHash, albumTitle, albumDescription,
                                        albumPath)
                                        VALUES
                                        (:hash, :title, :description, :path)");
            $addAlbum->execute(array('hash' => $hash, 'title' => $title, 'description' => $description,
                                     'path' => $path));
        }
    }
}
```

The error when I try it this way is 
`Fatal error:  Class 'gallery' not found in /home/opheliad/public_html/admin/photo-gallery/includes/class.admin_photo-gallery.php on line 10`

Comment: Not an answer, but this design could really use some improvement.

Comment: This is just part of a much larger class, yet to be constructed. Trying to avoid lots of redundancy. That and I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still learning the ins and outs of OOP. After a few minutes of research I came across `spl_autoload_register` in the PHP documentation.

I placed the `coreFunctions` class in `/includes/classes/coreFunctions.class.php` and the `gallery` class in `/includes/classes/gallery.class.php`

My code then became:

```
function cvfdAutoloader($class) {
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('cvfdAutoloader');
$mode = $_POST['mode'];

if (isset($mode)) {
    $gallery = new gallery;
    switch ($mode) {
        case 'addAlbum':
            $gallery->addAlbum($_POST['hash'], $_POST['title'],
                               $_POST['description']);
    }
}
```

And it works! Would someone care to shed some light on what exactly is happening here that is different from just including coreFunctions?

Comment: Try to move the class definition block to the top of your script on your old code. I think the point was that you try to instantiate a new object before you define its class

Comment: Ahh good thinking. I actually really like this setup, keeps everything more organized and I saved it as a code snippet in my IDE. I might give it a shot and report back, if I can remember

Answer (score 2):

<s>You'll need to `include` or `require` the file with the original class. Otherwise PHP won't see it.</s>

Make sure the include is successful, enable error reporting to see errors, or use `require` to trigger a fatal error on fail.

Comment: He should try echoing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. I'm suspecting it may include a trailing slash, which would break the path.

Comment: @NightMICU: And? No error no nothing? The script executes normally (until the error you normally get occurs)?

Comment: @JezenThomas: Yes, but that would mean the require would fail.

Comment: The path is correct, that's the same I use for everything. No errors at all for the include/require/include_once, etc. Just saying that Class gallery cannot be found